# c# adding checkboxes to panle wierd behavior

Tags: c#, winforms

i got a Class called AdvancePanle that drived from Panle, and i got a class call AdvnaceCheckBox that drived from CheckBox.

I created a AdvancePanle in my Form, and now i want to add some AdvnaceCheckBox's to it.
so i created this, simple method:

```
 private void addCheckBox()
    {
        AdvancedCheckBox checkbox;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            checkbox = new AdvancedCheckBox();
            checkbox.Location = new Point(0, i + 5);
            checkbox.Text = "bla" + i;
            selectablePanel1.Controls.Add(checkbox);
        }
    }
```

and i call this method in the Form onLoad:

```
 protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            addCheckBox();
            selectablePanel1.AutoScroll = true;

            base.OnLoad(e);
        }
```

but afther the Form is opened, I can see only 1 CheckBox in the Panle.
i tried playing with the position, but i alwys see only 1 checkbox.

am I adding the CheckBoxs in a worng way?

(sorry for my english)

Comment: The Location is clearly wrong, all these checkboxes are one pixel apart.  Use something like new Point(0, 5 + i * (checkbox.Height + 4));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're placing them too close to each other. `(0, 5+i)` will evaluate to:

```
(0,5)
(0,6)
(0,7)
(0,8)
...
```

Try this instead:

```
checkbox.Location = new Point(0, i*100 + 5);
```

or this:

```
checkbox.Location = new Point(0, i*checkbox.Height + 5);
```